# отправить запрос на удаленный сервер в виде JSON а ответ вернуть на фронт PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, php-curl

На фронте размещена форма с полями для логина и пароля. Данные с формы, с помощью ajax уходят на бек(tokener.php). Задача отправить запрос (сервер-сервер) в формате json c данными формы. в ответ нужно получить ответ формата json  с неким токеном сессии который необходимо вернуть на фронт.
Диагноз: CURL возвращает пустую строку. 
Пример кода:

```
    <?php

$userData=json_encode($_POST);

$token = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($token, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://тут урла сервера(не пропустил).com/account/externallogin',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array($userData))
));
$response = curl_exec($token);
$tokenFront = json_decode($response);
echo $tokenFront;
curl_close($token);
```

Сам Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'comp/tokener.php',
    type:'POST',
    cache:'false',
    data:$("#asset_auth").serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
      $("#sendPost").prop("disablled", true);
    },
    success: function(data){
      if (data!=''){
        $("#asset_auth").trigger("reset");
        alert(data);
      }

    }


  })
```

Ajax запрос в консоли(не формата JSON!):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ответ php:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это получаю если вернуть на фронт $userData (просто проверял):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Самые большие подозрения на CURL.
Ответ от сервера должен прийти в формате:

```
 { “errorCode” : 0, “responseMessage” : “some message”, “token” : “validtoken” }
```

Заранее спасибо!

-------------------------------Ответ Антона------------------------------

Попробовал предложенное вами решение:

```
<?php

$userData=json_encode($_POST);

$token = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($token, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://myurl/account/externallogin',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array($userData))
));
$response = curl_exec($token);
$error = curl_error($token);
if ($response !== false) {
  $tokenFront = json_decode($response);
  echo $tokenFront;
}
else {
  echo $error;
}
curl_close($token);
```

Пробовал как в оригинале, так и с небольшими изменениями:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это как раз и самое интересное что CURL либо возвращает FALSE либо ничего....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Это как раз и самое интересное что CURL либо возвращает FALSE либо ничего....

Ну, тут "либо что-то случилось, либо одно из двух".

1. Мне кажется, тут не все просто. Вы уверены, что без указания заголовка запроса "Content-Type: application/json" запрос будет обработан корректно? А без указания заголовка "Accept: application/json" внешний сервис отправит Вам точно JSON в виде ответа? Я думаю, стоит начать с того, чтобы открыть в браузере страницу логина этого внешнего сервиса и "инструментами разработчика" проверить все параметры отправляемого "штатно" запроса со страницы авторизации. В особенности - заголовки запроса.
2. Следующим шагом может быть попытка добиться от внешнего сервиса какого-либо ожидаемого отклика каким-нибудь инструментом, поддерживающим отправку запросов POST - консольной командой curl или дополнением браузера типа REST client. Для curl это может выглядеть примерно так:

```bsh
vagrant@homestead:~/$ curl -X POST "https://myurl/account/externallogin" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"Login\": \"test@gmail.com\", \"Password\": \"1234\"}"
{"token":null,"errorCode":2,"responseMessage":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: UserAccount"}vagrant@homestead:~/$
```

Как видите, "магия" с заголовками подействовала, отклик сервера получен. Для проверки корректности моего предположения отправим запрос без заголовков:

```bsh
vagrant@homestead:~/$ curl -X POST "https://myurl/account/externallogin" -d "{ \"Login\": \"test@gmail.com\", \"Password\": \"1234\"}"
vagrant@homestead:~/$
```

В ответ ожидаемо получили "мутабубу" в виде пустой строки. Предположение подтвердилось.

3. Только после этого переходите к отладке своего кода. Добавьте в него

```php
curl_setopt($token, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
]);
```

По идее - должно заработать. Далее - только правильно выдержать ожидаемые внешним сервисом имена параметров (обратите внимание на `"responseMessage":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: UserAccount"` в полученном отклике сервера). Удачи!

Comment: Игорь, большое спасибо за очень емкий ответ! К сожалению, не сразу его заметил, отчаялся и начал искать другой способ! Кстати, как раз ваши замечания по заголовкам "случайно" воплотил в другом методе)) Еще раз спасибо за уделенное время!

Answer (score 2):

Благодаря Igor Dyshlenko стало понятно в чем причина) Но я к тому времени уже успел выйти из ситуации вот такой штукой. Тут с заголовками справился случайно, но работает)

```
$url = 'https://myurl/account/externallogin';
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => [
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => "Content-type: application/json\r\n" .
                    "Accept: application/json\r\n" .
                    "Connection: close\r\n" .
                    "Content-length: " . strlen($userData) . "\r\n",
        'protocol_version' => 1.1,
        'content' => $userData
    ],
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false
    ]
)));

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что вы никак не анализируете возвращаемые ошибки.

Читаем [документацию](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-exec.php)

> Возвращает TRUE в случае успешного завершения или FALSE в случае возникновения ошибки. Однако, если установлена опция CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, при успешном завершении будет возвращен результат, а при неудаче - FALSE.
>
> Внимание
> Эта функция может возвращать как логическое значение FALSE, так и значение не типа boolean, которое приводится к FALSE. За более подробной информацией обратитесь к разделу Булев тип. Используйте оператор === для проверки значения, возвращаемого этой функцией.

Ваш код должен выглядеть как-то так

```
$response = curl_exec($token);
if ($response !== false) {
  $tokenFront = json_decode($response);
  echo $tokenFront;
} else {
  echo curl_error($token)
}
```

Comment: Спс видел это но смысла не много - все равно пустая строка. И нужно ли закрыть после этого сессию?(curl_close($token);
)

Comment: Антон, попробовал вывести curl_error($token). Результат без изменений. Описал внизу вопроса.